# How to silently install Unity on 16.04?

Tags: unity, gui, desktop-environments, docker

I am trying to create a Dockerfile that installs Visual Studio Code, which requires a desktop, on Ubuntu 16.04. I can get everything to build and run except for the last line of my Dockerfile:

```
apt-get install -y ubuntu-desktop
```

This line hangs as it expects input from the user (selecting a keyboard). *Is there a way to pass some values to this command so that it silently completes?*

Here is my complete Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends unzip libgtk2.0-0 libgconf-2-4 libnss3 libasound2
RUN apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt-get -f install -y libnotify4
RUN apt-get -y install npm
RUN apt-get -y install apt-transport-https
RUN npm install azure-cli -g
ADD https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=760868 vscode-amd64.deb
RUN dpkg -i vscode-amd64.deb
ADD http://download.nomachine.com/download/5.1/Linux/nomachine_5.1.26_1_amd64.deb nomachine_5.1.26_1_amd64.deb
RUN dpkg -i nomachine_5.1.26_1_amd64.deb
RUN apt-get install -y ubuntu-desktop
```